# Month end events on react big calendar are showing in the next month for example 2020-9-30 event shows in the october view

Tags: react-big-calendar

previous months event in react big calendar displays on the next month view, for example, 2020-9-30 event shows in October under the previous month but if I navigate back to September 30 there is nothing showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because January is month 0. So month 9 is October

```
{
   id: 0,
   title: 'Board meeting',
   start: new Date(2021, 8, 29, 9, 0, 0),
   end: new Date(2021, 8, 29, 13, 0, 0),
}
```

This displays on September 29th